# Can I get the history of a FB post via API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm starting to use FB graph API.
When I go in a group and read a post I can see, on the top of the post, a menu where there is a voice like: "Show the chronology of the post".
If I click on it I see every version of the message.
I didn't find any way to get the chronology of the post via API.

Is there a way or, at the moment, it is a non-available feature?

Thank you

Comment: i don´t think there is a way with the api